# Extending Master Model to child models in different directories

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been looking for an answer on this site and have found a few people who have asked the same question however I haven't found one that actually says the correct solutions.

I'm trying to figure out how I can have a master module hold certain variable values so that I can access them accordingly in other models. I'm running on a localserver on my computer and am also using the module plugin. I'm also auto-loading the master_model.

The problem is that I'm getting an error message saying the master_model can not be found from within the users_model.

```
$autoload['model'] = array('msgboxes', 'metatags', 'genfunc', 'adverts', 'master_model');

<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
* Master_model
*
* @author   Jeff Davidson
*/

class Master_model extends CI_Model 
{   
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    var $users_table = 'users';
    var $user_profiles_table = 'user_profiles';
    var $user_login_sessions_table = 'user_login_sessions';
    var $user_statuses_table = 'user_statuses';
    var $user_roles_table = 'user_roles';

}

/* End of file master_model.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/master_model.php */

<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
* Users
*
* This model represents user authentication data. It operates the following tables:
* - user account data,
* - user profiles
*
* @package  KOW Auth
* @author   Jeff Davidson
*/

class Users_model extends Master_model
{   
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


}

/* End of file users_model.php */
/* Location: ./application/modules/users/models/users_model.php */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the `Master_model` in the `application/core` directory and add the following code to the `application/config/config.php` file:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
    }
}
```

Read more [here](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY).